# Why is this an "overloading ambiguity" in gcc?

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguity

Why is this an error :
ie. arent long long and long double different types ?

```
../src/qry.cpp", line 5360: 
Error: Overloading ambiguity between "Row::updatePair(int, long long)" 
and "Row::updatePair(int, long double)".
```

Calling code:
.
.
       pRow -> updatePair(924, 0.0);
       pRow -> updatePair(925, 0.0);
.

Comment: Let us see more of your code especially the code that is calling updatePair

Comment: btw, it it legitimate to call this a "compile**r** error"?  Maybe it should sound as a "compile error"?

Comment: does updatePair have a default value for the second argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                 $1      $2
Row::updatePair(int, long long) // #1
Row::updatePair(int, long double) // #2


// updatePair(924, 0.0); 
//   int -> int (#1)  // $1#1
//   int -> int (#2)  // $1#2
//
//   double -> long long // $2#1
//   double -> long double // $2#2
```

In this case, both conversions in the first group are exact matches, while both conversions in the second group are conversions. They are equally ranked - it's like `int -> long` vs `int -> double`. The other call has the same types, just different values, so it exhibits the same behavior.

Only `float -> double` is a promotion, like only integer types smaller than int to int (and for some exotic platforms to unsigned int) are promotions. So the following wouldn't be ambiguous

```
                 $1      $2
Row::updatePair(int, double) // #1
Row::updatePair(int, long double) // #2


// updatePair(924, 0.0f); 
//   int -> int (#1)  // $1#1
//   int -> int (#2)  // $1#2
//
//   float -> double // $2#1 (promotion - not a ranked as conversion).
//   float -> long double // $2#2
```

In that case, the second argument has a better conversion sequence when converted to the parameter of `#1`.

Answer (score 3):

A constant `0.0` is of type double, which doesn't directly match your overloaded functions. You may expect your compiler to pick the `long double` version, but the compiler doesn't want to make that assumption for you.

You need to be more explicit about which version you want the compiler to call:

```
pRow -> updatePair(924, 0.0L);
```

will call the `long double` version.

or:

```
pRow -> updatePair(924, 0LL);
```

will call the `long long` version.